# What ist the best way to implement event based authorization in realtime web applications?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, real-time

I'm currently doing some research about the best way to implement event based authorization in a realtime web application.
In comparison with a normal REST call based application, published events are some kind of API-calls that need to be authorized on the server as there are different types of authorization levels. In the current REST application authorization is handled in general in the first step (Token Validation) and then call based by checking the user rights against the required ones for the call. Should this also be done that way in a realtime web application? Or is there some kind of mind-shift required in terms of application architecture?

Code sample from the current application (maybe bad sample for realtime requirement, but it shows the kind of authorization that is required very well):

```
app.get('/api/profile/email', passport.authenticate('bearer', {
    session: false
}), authorize('user.profile.email.read'), function (req, res) {
    // Do something and respond
});
```

I'm looking forward for some great input from you guys!

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways I have done it (if using sockets lets say) is to use a token stored in redis after the initial login or a refreshed token. It does a check on the token with authentication middleware to make sure it can continue or it sends an error. If you code it right, you can pass the token, pull it out and check it using your middleware.

```
   io.use(function(socket,next){
       var token = socket.request._query.tokenOfImmortality;
       tokenHandler.verify(token,next); //Function handles checking redis for access
   }
```

Comment: I also thought about that, the problem hereby is that the middleware only handles token based authorization for all calls, there is no way to authorize the event itself?

Comment: Oh ok, I think I get what you are asking. To clarify, you are asking if User A is an Admin and User B is a user, even if both are authenticated, only User A can utilize event "KickUserFromChat" because of his access level?

Comment: Exactly. I'm not sure if this is only a requirement because of bad architecture as it isn't implemented in any realtime framework I've seen so far. That's why I'm asking if there maybe is a better solution instead of trying to mimic a REST like event-driven architecture.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I am not sure if I know of any, but that is actually a really good project to start. I am going to do some research on some ways to implement this currently and if not it might be good to start something for the community. It'd essentially some kind of socket level middleware that can be packaged for auth or whatever else. For right now, if you create a socket handler object which has reference to any user auth stuff from the connection middleware, you'd be able to handle it on the socket level.